# Next JS next/link, not working in the initial page load

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

Hope all are doing good. I will directly move to the issue, I am trying to migrate my React-Typescript to Next JS for routing purpose. I am using Link -next/link but it is not working when the server is started but after a refresh routing is working fine. I am missing somewhere, could you please help me out?

```
<div>
      <Link href='/page1'  as={`/page1`}>
        <a>Page1</a>
      </Link>
      <p>Welcome to the page 2</p>
    </div>
```

After so many research I couldn't find anything in the interim, I randomly tried something, now the code is working as expected but I want to know how it is working. Below I have pasted the working code

```
<div>
      <Link href='/'  as={`/page1`}>
        <a>Page1</a>
      </Link>
      <p>Welcome to the page 2</p>
    </div>
```

I did nothing just did this
`href='/page1' to href='/'` or
`href='/page1' to href='/page'`
From the above scenarios, I used only one, now routing is working properly.
I am bit confused how it's working and I need proper explanation for this scenario.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: _"I am using Link -next/link but it is not working"_ - What do you mean by not working? What happens when you click the link exactly?

Comment: I am actually working in an e-commerce site where router are working in react but now we are trying to use next JS to improve the performance. We tried implementing next/link but when during the initial load the link <Link href='/page1'>Bills</Link> is not navigating to this page1. However, after refreshing or after routing directly in the url and then trying to use the link, then it is navigating as expected.